# How do I use jquery confirm box instead browser default confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I knew that it is not possible to change title or style of browser confirm box

How do I use `jquery confirm box` and `supress default confirm box`?

> can anyone give me link here.

thanks

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: You *could* overwrite the native `alert` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Out These jquery confirm box Plugins...

http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/confirm-box

Answer (score 1):

Due to the synchronous nature of the browser's alert boxes, there is no 100% drop-in replacement, however

http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/0.4.0rc1/

is a nice replacement that makes minimal coding changes to use.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use this library: http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ (try to search "Confirm" on the page). It's giva ability to write like `BootstrapDialog.confirm('Hi Apple, are you sure?');`